# REGEX Two expressions

Tags: regex

All,

I have a basic regex which is used in a wider automation which returns the reference point of the first digit in the string.

```
 Regex string: \d
```

Snippet of data:

```
 **AMBER YUR DE STE** 30367887462580                  1                                                        00355132

 **NIKITA YUAN**         318058763400580                  1                                                        00355133

 **SEAN D W** MC100050420965155230421            3                 14032887609303                        00355134
```

This enables me to extract results from the above:

```
AMBER YUR DE STE;
NIKITA YUAN;
SEAN D W MC;
```

I would like to know if its possible using regex that if the digit is preceded by a letter in this instance above

```
       **SEAN D W** MC100050420965155230421            3                 14032887609303                        00355134
```

The reference point of the First letter is gained instead "M" which would provide a result in the wider automation of:

SEAN D W

Please note the wider automation is utilising substring, find functionalities.

Comment: How about using `\s+[a-zA-Z]+\d+\s+` once(with your shown samples)? Onlne regex demo https://regex101.com/r/Z06X0l/1 for this regex.

Comment: You asked the same question more than once. If you have a follow up question, post it there, don't just create multiple questions

Comment: What about just taking the part between the `**`? i.e. `(?!\*).+(?=\*\*)`

Comment: Fragile logic. What if a name contains a digit, either accidentally or intentionally?